# Django Aggregation: Summation of Multiplication of two fields with ForienKey

Tags: django, aggregate, e-commerce

I have two model as below

```
class Product(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
     slug = models.SlugField()
     price = models.DecimalField(default=0.0,decimal_places=2,max_digits=15,validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])

     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.title)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.product.title}"

    def subtotal(self):
         return self.quantity * self.product.price
```

I want the total of all subtotal using aggregate but

```
total1 = OrderItem.objects.all().aggregate(total=Sum(F('product.price') * F('quantity')))['total']
```

returns `Cannot resolve keyword 'product.price' into field. Choices are: id, order, product, product_id, quantity` and

```
total2 = OrderItem.objects.all().aggregate(total=Sum(F('subtotal') * F('quantity')))['total']
```

returns `Cannot resolve keyword 'subtotal' into field. Choices are: id, order, product, product_id, quantity,` error

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that

```py
from django.db.models import Sum, F


total =  OrderItem.objects.all().aggregate(total=Sum(F('product__price') * F('quantity')))['total']
```

will do the work